# Which type of horse does a character get as an animal companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions, mount, cavalier

I'm currently playing a dwarfen cavalier.

According to the rules, he can chose a horse or a camel as a Mount.
But there are at least two types of horses: a light and a heavy one.
Since he is a heavily armored dwarf, I would like him to have a heavy horse. But the heavy horse is strictly better than a light horse in terms of stats and attack damage.

I cannot really figure out which one I would be supposed to have, since the rules do not seem to specify it at all. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A druidic animal companion horse

Your cavalier gets neither the [light horse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse/horse/) or the [heavy horse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse/heavy-horse/) as a mount; the cavalier's special feature states that:

> This mount functions as a druid’s animal companion, using the cavalier’s level as his effective druid level.

Thus, we refer to the rules for the [druid's animal companion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions), which has its own list of creature statistics to use as the base stats for such animal companions, which are then improved by adding the appropriate bonuses due to the druid's (or cavalier's) level.

The [horse animal companion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/animal-companions/#Horse) has the starting statistics:

> **Size** Large; **Speed** 50 ft.; **AC** +4 natural armor; **Attack** bite (1d4), 2 hooves* (1d6); **Ability Scores** Str 16, Dex 13, Con 15, Int 2, Wis 12, Cha 6; **Special Qualities** low-light vision, scent.

These horse stats don't agree exactly with either the light or heavy standard horses, but of course your mount will rapidly outclass such ordinary horses as you gain levels and it grows in hit dice and abilities. You might be especially interested in using the [charger](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/animal-companion-archetypes/charger-companion-archetype/) animal companion archetype, too, since that synergises with your cavalier abilities.

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot that animal companions and actual animals are treated as completely separate things in Pathfinder...